# What did Arya mean by "That's not you" in season 7 episode 2?

Tags: game-of-thrones

> On the way to Winterfell, after Arya met her direwolf Nymeria again and Nymeria went away                                                                         [image]

Why did she say "That's not you."?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77832/why-did-nymeria-leave-arya

Comment: Related questions from movies & TV [Is Arya Stark hallucinating in “Stormborn” (S07E02)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77796/is-arya-stark-hallucinating-in-stormborn-s07e02) and [Why did Nymeria leave Arya?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/77832/why-did-nymeria-leave-arya)

Comment: I didn't know that there is an answer in another stackexchange site. Should I delete the question then?

Comment: @user2191454 No that is fine. Cross-Site dupes happen a lot. Your question will now be our reference point to close any future questions about this as duplicate. It hasn't been asked here yet so it is not a duplicate. But if someone else asks the same question here again, we will be able to close it as dupe of your question

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This has been explained on HBO's official [MakingOfGameOfThrones Website](http://www.makinggameofthrones.com/production-diary/did-you-catch-this-702-thrones-throwback):

> Back in Season 1, Ned Stark comes across his younger daughter
> balancing on the stairs in a Red Keep hallway. Sitting together, **he
> offers Arya a glimpse of what her happy future could be: marriage and
> children**. Knowing herself even then, **the young girl looks at her
> father and simply says, “No, That’s not me.”**
>
> Now in Season 7, Arya asks her direwolf to come home with her, but is
> rejected by the creature. Disappointed at first, **she realizes that,
> just like her, Nymeria is not meant to be tamed.**

This is what the Show-runners had to say about the scene:

> David Benioff: This scene hearkens back to Season 1.
>
> [...]
>
> D.B. Weiss: **"That's not you" is a direct reference to what Arya herself said to her father** when her father painted this picture for her of the life she could have as the lady of a castle, and marrying some lord, and wearing a nice frilly dress.
>
> Arya is not domesticated and it makes total sense that her wolf wouldn't be either. And once the wolf walks away, at first she's heartbroken to have come this close, then she realises that **the wolf is doing exactly what she would do if she were that wolf**.
>
> <sub>**Game of Thrones: [Season 7 Episode 2: Inside the Episode (HBO)](https://youtu.be/TZB-bxAHv4s)**</sub>

<sub>**Credits:** This has been answered on MoviesSE by [Ghoti and Chips](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/42655/ghoti-and-chips). You can view the whole answer [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/77797/52541).</sub>

Comment: I had hoped the phrase meant, she noticed something was off with her wolf and bran was in its head, to say hi or something :/

Comment: @Philipp I thought arya meant that it was just a different dire wolf and that she mistook it for Nymeria. I was a big confused lol and now I feel stupid. This is  way better.